Auto Adding a google sheet to a new trello card
I am trying to get a google sheet template to duplicate, so that it doesn't change the original template, then automatically add it to a Trello card when it is added to a list.
I have tried many times but keep getting errors.
I have manged to get the trello card added and the spreadsheet duplicated in Google drive but I can't get it to add it to trello.
Can anyone help?
